# Creating 100m^2 grid automatically using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I need help on how to create a grid structure over my data set with each box being 100m^2.

That isn't manually doing it so I can calculate the features within each box?

Answer (score 10):

You have two options here. First one will create a new vector layer with a grid and the second one will just display a grid as overlay. What you are looking for is the first option. However, in case someone else is finding this question, the second option might be helpful as well.

Edit: of course 10m xy, not 100m as said below...

**First option:**

Run "Create Grid" tool from processing toolbox:

[image]

Select `Rectangle as Grid type`, `choose your extent` and enter `100 for Horizontal spacing and Vertical spacing`. `Choose a projected (metric) CRS` suitable for your area of interest.

Click run and a new temporary layer will be created. You can save this if you want.

**Second option:**

Go to `View --> Decorations --> Grid`. Enable it and `set intervals to 100`. Choose the style you wish it to have. This requires your project to be in a projected (metric) CRS.

[image]